# Using Scanner input for Driver class for a Method from a different class

Tags: java, class, input, driver

Okay, so I'm well aware that you can use the scanner for reading inputs and  setting outputs. However, I am using a multiple class package. In one class, I have an abstract method that has undefined parameters. It throws exception messages when invalid parameters are entered.

```
public class PersonalContact extends Contact
{
/*These are constants reserved for this class,
 * they can be called in this method, but never changed
 * in sub-classes.
 */
private String address;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zip;
// static limiters
private static int AGEMIN = 1;
private static int AGEMAX = 100;
private static int STATEMAX = 2;
private static int ZIPMAX = 5;
private static int CHARMAX = 30;

public PersonalContact(String name, int age, String address, String city, String state, String zip) 
{
    super(name, age);

    //We use the CHARMAX constant to prevent idiots from holding down the spacebar for +30 characters
    if (name.isEmpty() || name == null || name.length() > CHARMAX)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("You must enter a name value. ");
    }

    else if (age > AGEMAX || age < AGEMIN)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Please enter an age between 1 and 100");
    }

    else if (address.isEmpty() || address == null || address.length() > CHARMAX)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("You must provide your address. ");
    }

    else if (city.isEmpty() || city == null || city.length() > CHARMAX)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("You must provide your city name. ");
    }

    else if (state.isEmpty() || state == null || state.length() > STATEMAX )
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You must provide your abbreviated state name. ");
    }

    else if (zip.isEmpty() || zip == null || zip.length() > ZIPMAX )
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You must provide a 5 digit zipcode. ");
    }
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip; 
}
}
```

In my drivers class (the class that runs all the classes) I have a set method that has "try" and "catch" to see whats wrong and returns (throws) a message if there's an error. It works! However I want to know how to use the Scanner to set inputs in the driver class while using a method from the PersonalContact class. I've tried it and it wont let me. I've already searched for an answers and I ended up with nothing. Please help me?

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void personalConsole()
    {
    try
    {

        Contact personals = new PersonalContact("Robert", 22, "", "Seattle", "WA", "98144");

        System.out.println(personals);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Process Complete!");

}
}
```

I've already searched for an answer and I ended up with nothing. Please help me?

Comment: Do you want to create multiple objects of type `PersonalContact` in your driver class ? with each driver having its own `aadress` `city` `state` `zip` ?

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you mean by "multiple objects"?
I only need one driver class (unless you mean by having multiple methods each referring to different undefined parameters)

I tried setting variables for my PersonalContact(String address, int age....) using the Scanner class in my driver class, but it would not let me define values inside using the Scanner input.,

Contact personals = new PersonalContact("namegoeshere", agehere, "addresshere", "cityhere", "Abbreviated state here", "zipcodehere");

Comment: I like the idea to call a method on an object and check later if the object is null. That way you can't prevent a `NullPointerException` what over may suggest to do.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, I figured it out

I was supposed to setup two different scanner objects
to prevent input overlap (Scanner doesnt like alternating between string and int) before the try "method" was defined.

```
 public static void personalConsole()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanint = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter an age: ");
            int age = scanint.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter an address: ");
            String address = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter a city: ");
            String city = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter an state: ");
            String state = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter a zipcode: ");
            String zip = scanner.next();

    Contact personals = new PersonalContact(name, age, address, city, state, zip);

        System.out.println(personals);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Process Complete!");

}
```